# funcion contactenar textos en java

Tags: java

/**
* Desarrollar un algoritmo que permita concatenar dos cadenas (colocar
* la segunda inmediatamente después de la primera), hay que tener en
* cuenta que la cadena resultante tendrá un tamaño mayor que
* cualquiera de la cadenas operandos si son distintas de la cadena vacía
* (la cadena resultante debe quedar guardada en una variable aparte).
**/

````
```
public class Problema5 {
    
    //funcion que realizara la concatenaicion de los textos ingresados
    public static String contactenarTexto(String texto1, String texto2){
        String s = texto1 + ", " + texto2;
         return s;
    }
    
    //Realizar el proceso
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String texto1;
        String texto2;
        System.out.println("Ingresa el 1er texto");
        texto1 = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Ingresa el 2do texto");
        texto2 = sc.next();
        System.out.println(contactenarTexto(texto1, texto2));
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Al ingresar las siguientes lineas de texto1 "Esto en una poesia" texto2 "donde contara la siguiente", necesito obtener el resultado "Estos en una poesia donde contara la siguiente", pero obtengo es "Esto es"

Comment: Texto2 ponlo también como un string

Comment: Si fue un error de escritura, pero igual no soluciona el problema que tengo, el cual necesito se tenga en cuenta el texto completo ingresado, ya sea en uno, dos o mas string

Comment: Lo que ocupas para ingresar palabras con espacios es `nextLine();`

Comment: @OscarG muchas gracias, es lo que necesitaba. Ya me funciona correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Si queres que no figure la " , " tenes que borrarla de String s = texto1 + ", " + texto2;

Deberias usar el nextLine() para que te tome todo. Lo probe y funciono:

```
    System.out.println("Ingresa el 1er texto");
    texto1 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el 2do texto");
    texto2 = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ese era el pequeño detalle que necesitaba, y todo funciona correctamente. Exitos!!

Comment: No hay por que. saludos y suerte en tu practica!

Comment: Agradeceria que valides la respuesta asi la pregunta queda resuelta. Gracias!